# Zooming in blurs images in HTML5 using UIWebView on iPad

Tags: ios, image, html, zooming, blur

I'm currently developing an app that uses images in which the content and the background sits.
Basically the app has a fixed header menu, a fixed side menu and a content area as large as your screen.

When selecting a tab from either menu's, the content area is updated with an image.

all cases are on the iPad2

Case 1 - jQuery mobile + iScroll v4 + phonegap(cordova) imagesize (1024x1448):
when zooming in on the image, the image gets blurred. Also when using a .SVG as the image!

Case 2 - test project - UIWebView with scalePageToFit and a .jpg imagesize(2048x2896)
when zooming in on the image, it becomes blurred! HTML Text however remains sharp

Case 3 - test project - UIWebview with scalePageToFit and a .svg 
when zooming in on the image, it remains sharp.

What i WANT is a solution to the blurriness. Preferably not native.
If i use case1, an SVG and native zoom it also zooms both the menu's, which is not the desired behaviour.

It would be nice if someone could explain how other webpages / app's can contain image sharpness.(using html5).

Last but not least. Why are images on my iPhone's 4 gallery crisp when i zoom in, and not in my webview?